# Not able to return value of object from node to Angular

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, rest

Basically, I'm trying to return the data of query using POST in nodejs.I'm able to return the data, but its not returning the value of query. Instead, its sending data that is not required. How to get value from query and send it in json format?

```
router.post('/status', function(req, httpres, next){
 const spf_id = req.body.Spf_id;

 console.log("This is id",req.body.Status)
 pool.query("SELECT  s.spf_id ,s.status_id , m.status_id   ,l.status_id , su.status_id ,c.status_id  FROM sales as s INNER JOIN manager as  m ON m.spf_id = s.spf_id INNER JOIN logistics as  l ON l.spf_id = s.spf_id INNER JOIN support as su ON su.spf_id =   s.spf_id INNER JOIN collection  as c ON c.spf_id = s.spf_id WHERE s.spf_id = '"+spf_id+"'")
 .subscribe(
 data => {
 console.log("this is status",data.rows[0])
 return httpres.send(data);;
  //return httpres.status(200).send({ "Body"  :  Status_id['status'] })...
 //Multiple objects have to be returned
 }, err => {
 httpres.send('error',err);
 }) 
});
```

What it is returning:

Its returning 6 fields, that is exactly what I need. But the values inside those fields are wrong.

```
 Object { command: "SELECT", rowCount: 0, oid: null, rows: [], fields: (6) […], _parsers: (6) […], rowAsArray: false }
```

What it should return:
 [image]

Comment: The question is very specific to what `pool.query` is, this is the only relevant detail and it was omitted. Angular is not relevant. It doesn't matter whether you use JSON response with Angular or plain XHR.

Comment: Ya its specific to return value of query

Comment: What exactly `pool.query` is? What library are you using? Should we guess? Is it https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg ? The question should contain all relevant information in order to be answered.

Comment: yep.. I just want to pass multiple objects at once

Comment: Does 'yep' mean that you use `pg`? But `pg` doesn't have `subscribe` method, to my knowledge. Please, be as specific as possible if you're interested in getting an answer. Sorry, but it's impossible to help you without knowing which library it is and how you use it. The question is off-topic in its current state because it lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , which is required for SO questions.